# How to fix structure map DI error = Value cannot be null occurring in Controller build

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, structuremap

Scenario is ; VS2017,  MVC 5, StructureMap.MVC5

I get the following error:

> Error while building type BLL.MMCodes.MMCodesService."
>   InnerException  {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: String"}

Occurs in the "DoGetInstance" function when trying to run my app.

```
protected override object DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, string key) 
{
        IContainer container = (CurrentNestedContainer ?? Container);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) {
            return serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface
                ? container.TryGetInstance(serviceType)
                : container.GetInstance(serviceType);
        }

        return container.GetInstance(serviceType, key);
    }
```

The Service and interface

```
namespace BLL.MMCodes
{
    public interface IMMCodesService
    {
        bool ValidateAgainstBizRules(string MMCode, out string errorMessage);
        bool _UseEF
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

public class MMCodesService : IMMCodesService
{
    private string errorMessage;
    public MMCodesService()
    {
        ValidateAgainstBizRules( MMCode, out errorMessage);
    }

    #region vars
    public string MMCode { get; set; }
    private bool IsValid { get; set; }
    private List<string> Validations = new List<string>();
    #endregion

    public  bool _UseEF { get; set; }

    public bool ValidateAgainstBizRules(string mmCode, out string errorMessage)
    {....}
```

The Controller

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BLL.MMCodes;
using BusinessLayerDemoProject.Models;

namespace BusinessLayerDemoProject.Controllers
{
    public class MMCodeController : Controller
    {
        private IMMCodesService _iService;

        public MMCodeController(IMMCodesService service)
        {
            this._iService = service;
            this._iService._UseEF = true;
        }
```

I have tried several suggestions from all over the forums
eg. Changing the Properties in the `StructureMapDependencyScope` to cater for null in the HTTPContext and CurrentNestedContainer properties, but no success.

Comment: Thanks,..You are correct. I missed that completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this code:

```
public MMCodesService()
{
    ValidateAgainstBizRules( MMCode, out errorMessage);
}
```

The code inside the constructor is throwing an exception. Thus `StructureMap` is unable to pass it out to those objects that depend on it.

So, you *could* fix the code to make it not throw an exception.

**But**...

I am almost certain the code should just be removed / commented out. The code is being invoked inside a constructor. As such, by definition, `MMCode` hasn't been set - so running any kind of validation against it is pointless. As such, I recommend changing the code to:

```
public MMCodesService()
{
}
```